# select2 add option values on opening and refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

i have a select2 element that i need to add elements to when it is clicked by the user. to achieve this, i listen to the select2-opening event and add elements.

```
$('#select2_elem').on('select2-opening', function (evt) {
    $('#select2-elem').append('<option value="1">val1...</option>');
});
```

this works fine (i.e. appends the options in the DOM) except that i don't see the appended option(s) right away. is there any way to refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference to the current select element using `$(this)`.

```
$('#select2_elem').on('select2-opening', function (evt) {
    $(this).append('<option value="1">val1...</option>');
});
```